# Navigation Experimental and Pose Follower

Tags: ros, local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there any documentation for [navigation_experimental](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental), specially the [pose_follower](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/tree/hydro-devel/pose_follower) local planner?

I was wondering if it is compatible with the [ROS navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)? Can this [pose_follower](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/tree/hydro-devel/pose_follower) local planner be used as a plugin in ROS navigation stack?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

According to [this old post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/8238), seems pose_follower is not compatible with navfn, because the waypoints need to have orientation too, and navfn does.not provide this info

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198345/navigation-experimental-and-pose-follower/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, IIRC the `pose_follower` worked as a `base_local_planner` plugin before (with some previous ROS version I can´t remember :) ). It should be pretty straightforward to just try it out yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-27**:
Do you remember which global planner did you use with pose_follower. According to [this old post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/8238), seems it is not compatible with navfn, because the waypoints need to have orientation too, and navfn does.not provide this info

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-11-28**:
The spbl_lattice_planner probably would be a good choice, as it takes the vehicle's kinematic capabilities into account.